# Python: faster alternative for itertools.product()?

Tags: python, python-itertools

I'm trying to find all possible combinations of a list with length = 22 & element values = 1-9.

When I use `[i for i in itertools.product(range(1, 10), repeat=22)]`, Python crashes. Does Python have a faster alternative?

Comment: Do you need a list of them, or can you use them 1 by 1? A generator may be a good solution...

Comment: Just wanted to say the same thing ... just do: for i in itertools.product(range(1, 10), repeat=22)

Comment: To add to @JonSurrell's comment, a list of all such values would have 984,770,902,183,611,232,881 (almost a sextillion!) elements.  Do you really need them all at once?

Comment: Even if you had enough memory to store them all, you're not going to be able to iterate through them all -- it would take too long.  Maybe you should edit your question to describe your actual goal; this is very likely an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Well, you try to create `9**22`, or `984770902183611232881` elements. Can you estimate memory requirements for that many objects?

Comment: @DSM I have a 9x9 sudoku with 22 open spots. I know there are many options to efficiently solve this, but I'm currently investigating whether it's possible to simply 'brute force' the solution. I.e. find all possible ways to fill the empty cells, validate each resulting sudoku and only keep the valid solutions.

Comment: you can easily calculate the brute force complexity ... see above ... it probably only takes an hour or two (or until the heat death of the universe)

Comment: No, it is not realistically possible to brute-force a solution by checking nearly 10^21 possible solutions.

Comment: Well, it was worth trying. However, the generator surely is a better option than the list comprehension. Going to leave my computer on for the night and see if it will work :-) Thanks everyone!

Comment: @Algorithm_NL What was the result of the experiment?

Comment: Sudoku has rules which help. Numbers can't repeat in rows, columns or grids, so if you were going to brute-force it, you could narrow it down by a few universes of magnitude by implementing those same rules in your data structure. You'd start by inputting the existing values & coordinates of the 9x9 grid , 81 - 22 = 59 cells. Those 59 cells and their coordinates should reduce the set of values for each row, column, grid and you can then just mini-brute force through those combinations. Each row, column, grid is max length 9. Python's shallow copy is helpful here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As everyone commented, try using the generator directly instead of using a list. *finding* all combinations is unclear. If you need to print them, do this:

```
for i in itertools.product(range(1, 10), repeat=22):
    ... #Don't actually print, that may block your computer for a long time.
```

if you need to do something on those values, then tell us what you need.

Comment: Thanks, I was also stuck on a very similar problem and you have solved it. I was in the XY problem mode of thinking.

Comment: Pro tip for future viewers... don't print them

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience @Davos. :/

Comment: Don't worry, I read the comments on the question first :) I've also read the manual: [Essential Copying and Pasting from Stack Overflow](https://legacy.gitbook.com/book/tra38/essential-copying-and-pasting-from-stack-overflow/details) Good job redacting the `print`, it's probably the `repeat=22` part that is dangerous though.