# Python: System getting stuck during list generation via product function, without explicit parallel processing

Tags: python, list, memory

I'm using the list function with the product function to create a list whose elements are made of m digits (10) out of n types(0 to 7), which should yield all possible patterns.

Using n=8, I first use smaller numbers for m to get the process going, it works fine till m=8.

My program is as follows

```
import time
from itertools import product

start_time = time.time()
repeatnum=8
patternnum=8
list1=list(product(range(0,patternnum), repeat=repeatnum))
print(len(list1))

print("Time taken for list is  --- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

At n=8(repeatnum), the time taken is about 3 seconds. As I use n=9, not only the python program (within IDLE/Spyder/Windows CLI), but the whole system starts behaving sluggishly, which has not happened before. (Usually only the python program takes time, but the other programs on the computer run normally.)

I don't get any error messages till I stop the execution, neither does the processor heat up as one would expect. Just that the system shows choppy and time delayed behaviour for other functions

As a result, I have to end the python program execution (which is also not straightforward) and the general usability of the system also improves. What could be causing this behaviour? Is there some auto-parallelization happening automatically? Or I am just running out of RAM memory?

System Info:

```
System Manufacturer HP
System Model    HP ProBook 640 G2
System Type x64-based PC
Processor   Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6300U CPU @ 2.40GHz, 2401 Mhz, 2 Core(s), 4 Logical Processor(s), 8 GB RAM
```

Comment: `itertools.product` evaluates its arguments eagerly: [Does itertools.product evaluate its arguments lazily?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45586863/does-itertools-product-lazy-evaluate-its-arguments). The size of the pool gets larger and larger as `n` increases, increasing memory use and time to compute each product.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34316346/python-faster-alternative-for-itertools-product Solves my problem exactly. Thanks for the help.